# How did Kylo Ren get Darth Vader's helmet?

Tags: the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, we can see Kylo Ren has the helmet of Darth Vader. How did Kylo get Darth Vader's helmet?

Comment: Have you considered using a spell-checker and/or grammar-checking tool like Grammarly? This is almost incomprehensible.

Comment: I've removed your second question (about whether Vader's head was still in the helmet) as that would have made this too broad.

Comment: Are you asking "how is it possible", or are you asking "was a description of the particular trials and events involved ever given"? I mean, "how it's possible" is "his parents were there".

Comment: I also want to know whether Vader's head in the helmet or not.

Comment: @JohnDavies - Burned to ashes, it seems

Answer (score 15):

The *Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Visual Dictionary* notes that the helmet was scavenged from [the pyre on Endor](https://youtu.be/rA1dQtGbqw4?t=7) on which Vader's body was burned.

Presumably Ren acquired it from whoever scavenged the pyre, or from someone who acquired it from whoever scavenged the pyre*

<sub><sub>* or from someone who acquired it from someone who acquired it from whoever scavenged the pyre</sub></sub>

[image]

---

The (canon) short story [*The Perfect Weapon*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Perfect_Weapon) features young [Bazine Netal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bazine_Netal#cite_note-PerfectWeapon-2) being commissioned by the First Order to steal a mysterious case from a Stormtrooper captain that had fought in the Battle of Endor.

While the clear implication is that this is Vader's helmet (looted from the Ewok village and then transferred to Kylo Ren via Netal), we never actually find out [what's in the box](https://media.giphy.com/media/UTvayOxPBrl8y5BzIP/giphy.gif).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152186/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-how-did-kylo-ren-get-darth-vaders-helmet); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.